# how to use case sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need assign value word by numeric so i tried below code.but its showing error"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'."

```
declare @ww int

set @ww=1
case @ww
WHEN  '1' THEN  print='one'

ELSE NULL
```

where i made error...?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* in SQL Server. It computes a value. It's not a control flow *statement*. And can you give a more realistic example of what you're trying to achive? At the moment, I just optimize this by eye and re-write your entire piece of code as `print='one'` (whatever that's meant to mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

In there it states "CASE can be used in any statement or clause that allows a valid expression. For example, you can use CASE in statements such as SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and SET, and in clauses such as select_list, IN, WHERE, ORDER BY, and HAVING. ". This is not the case here.

In response to your comment (as you cannot line break in comments)

```
declare @ww int

set @ww=1
if @ww = 1
SET @result = 'one'
```

Sorry for the editting, my rabbit ran across my keyboard.

Comment: i need this code" if(@fun_level == 1)
  @result='one'" how to get it

Answer (score 1):

**You can't use Case in stand alone, instead use it like this**

```
declare @ww int
set @ww=1
SELECT CASE @ww 
  WHEN '1' THEN 'one'
ELSE NULL 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was:: you did not write 'end' after case statement.